# Excel: "Too many different cell formats" ERROR

Tags: excel

Everytime I try to open a file with Excel, I get the error: "Too many different cell formats".  I've looked up the problem several times and still haven't found the answer. Plus, when I try to open the file, I can't do anything until the error goes away. Problem is: IT NEVER GOES AWAY. No matter how many times I click "OK" or try and exit out of the error, it immediately comes back. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: I seemed to have bypassed the issue by holding down **ALT+F4**, but I still want to know why the error comes up.

Comment: You say you searched this.  Can you then explain how [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/213904) did not work for you?

Comment: Each solution in this article is angled more towards preventing the problem rather than fixing it. The only solution that offers fixing it requires running a cleaner through your spread sheet. I ended up creating a new spread sheet with less files in it. Thanks for the link though, this helped with a different problem I had!